# How can I $filter on Dictionary<string, string> using OData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, odata

**I have an OData query enabled action on my Controller that Returns an Asset.**

**C# Model.**

```
var asset = new Asset()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Name = "Cool Asset Yo",
    Url = "http://test/test.asset",
    Tags = new[] {"test"},
    Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"platform", "android"},
        {"dim_depth", "1.0"},
        {"dim_height", "1.0"},
        {"dim_width", "1.0"},
        {"item_type", "Trim"}
    }
}
```

**Returned JSON**

```
 [
      {
        "name": "Cool Asset Yo",
        "properties": {
          "platform": "android",
          "dim_depth": "1.0",
          "dim_height": "1.0",
          "dim_width": "1.0",
          "item_type": "Trim"
        },
        "tags": [
          "test"
        ],
        "url": "http://test/test.asset",
        "id": "77d9b9df-4f4b-4fad-a1d3-af5075d52a62",
      }
 ]
```

**Example Queries that work!**

- `api/Asset?$filter=startswith(name, 'Cool')`
- `api/Asset?$filter=tags/any(tag eq 'test')`
- `api/Asset?$filter=id eq '77d9b9df-4f4b-4fad-a1d3-af5075d52a62'`

**And NOW for the fail :-(**

- `api/Asset?$filter=properties/platform eq 'Android'`

  - *Error: The parent value for a property access of a property 'platform' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.*
- `api/Asset?$filter=properties/any(props: props/platform eq 'Android')`

  - *Error: Could not find a property named 'platform' on type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair_2OfString_String'.*
- `api/Asset?$filter=properties/any(keyValue: keyValue('platform') eq 'Android')`

  - *Error: An unknown function with name 'keyValue' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.*
- `api/Asset?$filter=properties/any(keyValue: keyValue eq 'Android')`

  - *Error: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair_2OfString_String' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'.*
- `api/Asset?$filter=properties['platform'] eq 'Android'`

  - *Error: Syntax error at position 31 in 'properties['platform'] eq 'Android''.*

How do I get a list of assets with the 'platform' of 'Android'? I see examples of in the [Microsoft Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4) of Generic Dictionaries being used in a model, I don't see any $filter examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenarios, "Properties" looks a dictionary property, but the dictionary property is not a built-in property in OData.

Besides, your payload looks a normal JSON serialized output. It's not odata payload.

You said you saw examples of in the [Microsoft Documents of Generic Dictionaries being used in a model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4), it's a usage of dynamic property. Please pay attention that "**It's different between your scenario (dictionary) and the dynamic property**".

**Most important**, Web API OData now supports to filter on the dynamic property.
See my test cases in the  [commit](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/commit/b9d513ba724ac35776b4e37f762b69759f9d325f)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: This does help. The dynamic properties are different than a plain dictionary. Furthermore, they seem to only work if you have an OData controller, not just a query enabled action.

Comment: Yes, you are correct the result is not an OData collection payload.

Answer (score 1):

[Sam Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304931/sam-xu) is correct, a dictionary property is not supported in OData, also dynamic property did not work in my scenario. I was forced to change my properties bag to be a list of a custom key-value type.

**C# Model.**

```
var asset = new Asset()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Name = "Cool Asset Yo",
    Url = "http://test/test.asset",
    Tags = new[] {"test"},
    Properties = new List<KeyValue>
    {
        new KeyValue("platform", "android"),
        new KeyValue("dim_depth", "1.0"),
        new KeyValue("dim_height", "1.0"),
        new KeyValue("dim_width", "1.0"),
        new KeyValue("item_type", "Trim")
    }
}
```

**Returned JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Cool Asset Yo",
    "properties": [
      {
        "key": "platform",
        "value": "android"
      },
      {
        "key": "dim_depth",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "key": "dim_height",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "key": "dim_width",
        "value": "1.0"
      },
      {
        "key": "item_type",
        "value": "Trim"
      }
    ],
    "tags": [
      "test"
    ],
    "url": "http://test/test.asset",
    "id": "77d9b9df-4f4b-4fad-a1d3-af5075d52a62",
  }
]
```

**Example Queries that work!**

```
api/Asset?$filter=properties/any(keyValue: keyValue/key eq 'platform' and keyValue/value eq '50129486')
```